# Windows: Different ways to terminate a process from kernel

Tags: c, windows, kernel, windows-kernel

There is this one particular process I can't terminate with ZwTerminateProcess directly because its driver registers a callback for said function to protect itself.

Other methods:

- Injecting a DLL and calling ExitProcess
- Attaching to its address space with KeAttachProcess then calling ZwTerminateProcess (causes BSOD IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL)
- MmUnmapViewOfSection (causes BSOD because program tries to write to unreadable memory)

How does process hacker do it?

Comment: process hacker is open source, take a look?

Comment: I didn't know that. I feel dumb. I'll post an answer when I find it.

Comment: Ah, I see. It uses ObOpenObjectByPointer. Using ZwOpenProcess directly was my problem. I'm new to kernel programming obviously.

Comment: Irrelevant but as I am not able to ask any more questions, I'll ask it here. How do I use environment variables in KM? What function will allow me to do this? In UM there is ExpandEnvironmentStrings.

Answer (score 0):

As `ExpandEnvironmentSettings` is in `kernel32.dll`, you should be able to call it using the undocumented kernel routine `KeUserModeCallback`, as described in https://thisissecurity.net/2014/04/08/how-to-run-userland-code-from-the-kernel-on-windows/.